# Unity top down character movement animation goes sideways

Tags: unity, c#, game-mechanics

I am struggling with the animation handling for my top down character movement.

The game is a 3D top down game. The character is always facing in the same direction as the pointer and I have animations for moving forward, sideways and backward.

The idea is to identify the direction so the correct animation can be played. the big problem is it has to be relative to the character's view direction.

I'm struggling how to choose the right movement animation.

I tried different things and the easiest idea I had was to use this:

```
movementDir = Transform.position - oldPosition
```

and a vector for the direction the character is looking.

However, the `movementDir` is switching between the correct value and 0,0,0 and I don't understand why.

The character is moving with constant speed and the actual position should always be different while moving but somehow it is as if in some frames the character is still at the same position as the frame before.

I've tried to find a solution for this on google but without luck.

Comment: Don't forget to show us how you move your character.

Comment: Have you tried something like this when setting `oldPosition`? `if (transform.position != oldPosition) oldPosition = transform.position)`